# Struggling with Borel's Strong Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability-theory

I'm struggling with a passage from page 240 of "Measure theory and probability theory" by Krishna and Soumendra regarding the proof of Borel's strong law of large numbers.

> Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of random variables i.i.d having the same mean $\mu$ and for which $E[X_n^4]<\infty$ holds, define $\bar{X_n}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ and $Y_i=(X_i - \mu)$. Then
> \begin{gather}
> E\left((\bar{X}_n - \mu)^4\right) \\ 
> =\frac{1}{n^4}E\left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i  \right)^4\right) \\
> =\frac{1}{n^4} \left(nE(Y_1^4) + 3n(n-1)(E(Y_1^2))^2 \right) \\
> = O(\frac{1}{n^2})
> \end{gather}

I can't get the passages behind the second equality. I'm looking for an explanation, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the following equality:

$(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i)^4=\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^4+\binom{4}{1}\sum_{1\leq j<m\leq n} Y_j^3Y_m+\binom{4}{2}\sum_{1\leq j<m\leq n} Y_j^2Y_m^2+$

$+2\binom{4}{2}\sum_{1\leq j<m<r\leq n}Y_j^2Y_mY_r+4!\sum_{1\leq j<m<r<s\leq n}Y_jY_mY_rY_s$

Now we take the expectation on both sides of the equality. Using the fact that the random variables $Y_i$ are independent (and so the expectation of a product is just the product of expectations) and have expectation $0$ we automatically get rid of most sums in the right hand side. We are left with:

$\mathbb{E}[(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i)^4]=\sum_{j=1}^n\mathbb{E}[Y_j^4]+\binom{4}{2}\sum_{1\leq j<m\leq n}\mathbb{E}[Y_j^2]\mathbb{E}[Y_m^2]=n\mathbb{E}[Y_1^4]+6\binom{n}{2}\mathbb{E}[Y_1^2]\mathbb{E}[Y_1^2]=$

$=n\mathbb{E}[Y_1^4]+3n(n-1)(\mathbb{E}[Y_1^2])^2$

Comment: If I'm not wrong this kind of manipulation fall under the name of " product identities". I'm wondering if you have some suggestion to gain such confidence in it. Thank you.

Comment: @Giovanni Barbarani You mean the expansion of $(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i)^4$? This is just a formula, a generalization of the Newton binomial theorem.